# Uninstalling IBM WebSphere

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I am uninstalling WebSphere from my drive E by using IBM installation Manager, during uninstallation it gives me the following error:
 "E:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\clearClassCache.bat" not found"

I have searched and found that the location of clearClassCache.bat file is:

"E:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\bin"

Should i copy the file from AppSrv01\bin to AppServer\bin and retry uninstallation? Or is there any other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Scripts under AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\bin should also be under AppServer\bin, but the copy under profiles is often (always?) modified to be profile-specific. So I doubt that copying it will work for you.

That specific script is under my AppServer\bin, so it seems it's been removed in your case. Possibly from the earlier part of the uninstallation.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda an old question but here it goes.

Uninstall script is in <application_server>\uninstall folder. Not sure what is called under Windows but on Linux it is <application_server>\uninstall\uninstall ( yes script has the same name as folder)